Sitecore Publishing Service - Item publish queue position changed
We are publishing two items one by one using Publishing service. But the order changed in the publishing service queue. How to publish the items in the same order?
 PublishManager.PublishItem(...item1)
 PublishManager.PublishItem(...item2)


To enforce the same order of item publishing in Sitecore Publishing Service, follow these steps:

Access the Publishing Service Configuration:

Navigate to the App_Config\Include folder of your Sitecore instance
where the Publishing Service is installed.
Locate the Sitecore.Publishing.Service.config file.


Adjust the Number of Workers:

Open Sitecore.Publishing.Service.config in a text editor.

Find the  section which configures the publishing engine.

By default, the MaxWorkers setting is typically set to a value
greater than 1 to enable parallel processing. To enforce sequential
processing (i.e., processing items in the order they are queued), set MaxWorkers to 1:






 <Engine><MaxWorkers>1</MaxWorkers>
 <!-- Other settings -->    </Engine>


Save and Deploy

Save the Sitecore.Publishing.Service.config file.
Restart the Sitecore Publishing Service for the changes to take
effect. You can restart it via IIS or using the Services management
console.




We do have that settings in the Config file

I don't believe we can control the order of publishing using Publishing service as multiple items can be published at the same time using SPS. But you can read the Handle of the job to fetch the status when Item 1 is published. When the job status for Item 1 is completed, thereafter you can start publishing Item 2.
You can refer below code to check publishing status.
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer;
using Sitecore.Jobs;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

public void PublishItemsInOrder(Item item1, Item item2)
{
   Handle handle = publishingManager.PublishItem(item1);
   var jobStatus = publishingManager.GetStatus(handle);

  if(jobStatus != null && jobStatus.IsDone){
    // Publish Item 2
    publishingManager.PublishItem(item2);
  }
  else if (jobStatus != null && (jobStatus.State == JobState.Running || jobStatus.State == JobState.Queued)){
    //keep on polling this
    SheerResponse.Timer("PublishItemsInOrder", 1000);
  }
}

This way will allow you to publish the items in the order as desired.
Hope this helps!!!

Is this handle stop further code execution until jobs completed?

@Astle No it wont step any execution as it will execute as a separate thread.

@Astle you also use 'await Task.Delay' instead of 'SheerResponse.Timer' to delay without blocking main thread....

Use a callback or event to trigger the second publish operation once the first one is completed. This ensures that the second item is published only after the first one is done.
void PublishItem(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item, Action callback)
{
    var options = new Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishOptions(item.Database, databases, Sitecore.Publishing.PublishMode.SingleItem, item.Language, DateTime.Now);
    PublishManager.PublishItem(options);

    // Call the callback function after publishing
    callback?.Invoke();
}

// Publish the first item and then the second one in the callback
PublishItem(item1, () => {
    PublishItem(item2, null);
});

